# Webpack CSS and JS not being minifed in dev mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify

I have this code in my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/assets/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    filename: "assets/js/bundle.js",
    publicPath: "",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin(), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //babel
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
        },
      },
      //style and css extract
      {
        test: [/.css$|.scss$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: () => [
                require("autoprefixer")({
                  browsers: ["> 1%", "last 2 versions"],
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      //image file loader
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|pdf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/media/",
              publicPath: "../media/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      //fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/fonts/",
              publicPath: "../fonts",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@scss": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/scss"),
      "@js": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/js"),
      "@media": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/media"),
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
    modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "assets/css/styles.css",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Rejaur Rahman | Web Developer",
      template: "src/index.html",
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      },
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
      server: { baseDir: ["dist"] },
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/media"),
          to: "assets/media",
        },
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/favicons"),
          to: "assets/favicons",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 1000000,
    maxAssetSize: 1000000,
  },
};
```

The issue is that when I run *npm run dev* it doesn't minify the css and js. Ideally I want to minify them and inject in my html document like internal css and js.

My package.json here

```
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.4.1",
"node-sass": "^4.0.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
"style-loader": "^2.0.0",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
"webpack": "^4.46.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
```

Comment: Minimized code is not very useful for debugging.

Comment: you might need to use the prod mode for that.

Comment: yes i know but I am just trying to find that option where I can control it to minimize it in debug mode also

Comment: also, are there any options to output the css and js in head of html document?